# Is there any matrix $A$ for which $A^{\dagger}A=AA^{\dagger}$ but $A\neq A^{\dagger}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I encountered the definition of a [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) matrix:

$$A^*A = AA^*$$

Whereas the definition of a [hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix) matrix is:

$$A^{\dagger}=A$$

From this it follows that $A^{\dagger}A=AA^{\dagger}$, very similar to the definition of the normal matrix.

Does it work in the other way round? I.e., are there matrices for which it holds that $A^{\dagger}A=AA^{\dagger}$ but $A^{\dagger}=A$ does not?

Comment: This even happens when the dimension is $1$, ie. scalars.  $2\cdot 3 = 3\cdot 2$ but $2\neq 3$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are many such matrices. Hermitian matrices are just one type of normal matrix, but there are many other types of normal matrices. For example, you could consider *skew-Hermitian matrices*, which are not generally Hermitian. These matrices are ones that satisfy $A^* = -A$ (which implies $A^* A = AA^*$), and such $A$ is Hermitian if and only if $A = -A$, that is, iff $A = O$. For example take $A = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $A$ is normal but $A^{*} \neq A$.

In fact, your question is answered in the Wikipedia page on normal matrices that you linked, in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix#Special_cases).

Answer (score 0):

For unitary matrix $A$, we always have $AA^\dagger=I=A^\dagger A$, but this does not mean $A=A^\dagger$.